# Create executable tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, scipy, pyinstaller

I am trying to create an executable of a code with libraries like *Tkinter*, *Pandas* and *Pillow*.

I used the `pyinstllaer`, `cx_freeze` and `scipy` but I get an error or the .exe has a size not according to what you want (ex: 500 mb).

What I want to get is an executable to be able to open it in Windows and / or MAC to be used by most users.

The code can be something irrelevant for this question, so I need or maybe we need all are understandable tips or tutorials to be able to create an executable, since in the revised questions only specific cases are being solved and not common cases like what I am describing . Thank you.

Here I show the code

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
#from sismorresistente import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from PIL import Image
import pandas as pd
import os

class sismicidad():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vent_sismi = tk.Tk()
        self.vent_sismi.iconbitmap("sismo_ico_1.ico")
        self.vent_sismi.title("SISMICIDAD")
        self.pest_sismor = ttk.Notebook(self.vent_sismi)
        self.pest_sismor.grid(row=0, column = 0)
        self.sismorresistente_1()
        self.perf_suelos()
        self.zona_sismi()
        self.sismor_funcion()
        self.z_sismi_funcion()
        self.vent_sismi.mainloop()

#Funciones para la estructura de la pestaña SONAS SISMORRESISTENTE:
    def sismorresistente_1(self):
        ...
#Funcion de CERRAR:
    def cerrar_sismicidad(self):
        self.vent_sismi.destroy()

#Funciones para la estructura de la pestaña de PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def perf_suelos(self):
        ...
    #Mostrar Tabla de Vs:
    def abrir_vs(self):
        self.im = Image.open("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/tabla_perf.jpg")
        self.im.show()

    #Funciones para PERFILES DE SUELOS:
    def sismor_funcion(self,event=None):

        self.x1=self.entry_1.get()

        try:
            self.x1=int(self.x1)

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir solo números enteros.")

        while True:
            if self.x1 > 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S0: Roca Dura.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 500 and self.x1 <= 1500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S1: Roca y Suelos muy rigidos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 180 and self.x1 <= 500:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S2: Suelos Intermedios.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 > 0 and self.x1 <= 180:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="Perfil tipo S3: Suelos Blandos.", font = "helvetica 12", foreground= "blue")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            elif self.x1 == 0:
                self.eti_lab_11.configure(text="")
                self.eti_lab_11.grid(row=3, column=0, padx=20, pady=10)

            break

#Funciones para la estrutura de la pestaña ZONAS SISMICAS:
    def zona_sismi(self, event=None):
        ...
    def abrir_norma(self):
        os.popen("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/norma_tecnica_e_030.pdf")

    def z_sismi_funcion(self, event=None):

        self.datos = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Miguel Mogollòn/Desktop/sismicidad/distri_sism_1.csv", encoding="latin9", sep=";")
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(self.datos)

        self.x2 = self.entry_2.get()

        try:
            self.x2=str(self.x2)

        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showwarning("Error", "Escribir el distrito.")

        #while True:

        self.x2 = str.upper(self.x2)

        for self.idx in self.df.index:

            if self.df.DISTRITO[self.idx] == self.x2:
                self.eti_lab_14.configure(text = f"La zona sismica de '{self.x2}' es: {self.df.ZONA_SISMICA[self.idx]}", font="helvetica 12", foreground = "blue")
                #self.eti_lab_14.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
                self.eti_lab_14.place(x=30, y=70)
                break
        else:
            self.eti_lab_14.configure(text=f"Ingrese el distrito correcto",font="helvetica 12", foreground="blue")
            self.eti_lab_14.place(x=30, y=70)
            #self.eti_lab_14.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)

aplicacion = sismicidad()
```

Here I show what comes out when I want to open the executable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJDyd.png)

Comment: What python version? Is it python 3.8?

Comment: @DYB yes is python 3.7.

Comment: Is there a problem with pyinstaller or you just want to know how? If there is a problem can you put the error?

Comment: What happens is that I get no error when creating the executable using `scipy` (platform); The executable is created but when opening the executable (I use `tkinter`) the cmd window appears and disappears.

Comment: what about the tkinter window?

Comment: It just doesn't open.

Comment: I use pyinstaller to make an .exe for windows with tkinter all the time. Are you sure "The code can be something irrelevant for this question"? Maybe there's something in the code or command you put to make this .exe, causing this problem.

Comment: We need far more information than this. _The code can be something irrelevant for this question_ Does that include how you used pyinsyaller etc. ?

Comment: I added the code for your better understanding.

Comment: ``No module name PIL``,it seems that you haven't import PIL in your `sismicidad.py`

Comment: Resolved!! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In python version 3.8, pyinstaller has issues. If a direct install via pip doesn't help (`pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz`), try downgrading to python version 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

I used the `pyinstaller` platform to compile it into the executable with the code in the CMD window:

```
pip install auto-py-to-exe
```

```
auto-py-to-exe
```

Resolved!! Thank you